# How can I use the upright integral symbol of Stix Two Math font?

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, stix

Is there a way to use the *upright* integral symbol from the recently released Stix Two Math font? Probably a solution, if there is one, would require the package unicode-math and xelatex or lualatex. That'd be OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not yet a STIX Two distribution for `pdflatex`, so you need XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX with `unicode-math`.

According to the specs, the upright integrals are obtained via `ss08`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[StylisticSet=08]

\begin{document}

\[
\int \iint \iiint \oint
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the option, we get

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. In case I need similar info: where is this "specs" located (link, document name, etc.)?

Comment: @balcinus The downloaded ZIP file contains a `docs` folder with `STIX_2.0.0_stylistic_sets.pdf` inside it.